# Javascript to calculate a fictional date of birth from todays date and fixed age

Tags: javascript

I have an interactive story in which I need to calculate what someones year of birth is based on these two facts:

1. The character is 32 years old
2. The character was born on May the 20th

So far I'm using the following to establish the date:

```
var currentDate = new Date()
var day = currentDate.getDate()
var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1
var year = currentDate.getFullYear();
```

What Javascript could I then use to figure out what the year of birth would need to be for the above facts to remain true?

I hope that makes sense and thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Do you want to find date of birth on the base of Age (from current date)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, something like this:

```
var dateOfBirth;
if(month > 5 || (month === 5 && day > 20))
    dateOfBirth = (year - 32) + '/05/20';
else
    dateOfBirth = (year - 33) + '/05/20';
```

Comment: Thanks, this was returning the wrong result (appears to be out by a  year) so have gone with the suggestion below. Thanks for your help.

Comment: My apologies, it was me who was out by a year! Just had to make one change (day >= 20) and it works perfectly. Thank you @kamilkp

Answer (score 0):

> 1.The character is 32 years old
>   2.The character was born on May the 20th

Months in javascript Dates are zero indexed. The idea is to find the birth year based on the age and todays date, then set the values for month and day.

```
var ageInYears = 32;
var birthMonth = 'May';
var birthDay   = '20th';

var d = new Date();
var currentMonth = d.getMonth();
var currentDate  = d.getDate();
var months = {january:0, february:1, march:2, april:3, may:4, june:5, july:6,
              august:7, september:8, october:9, november:10, december:12};
var birthMonthNum = months[birthMonth.toLowerCase()];
var birthDate = parseInt(birthDay);
var birthYear = d.getFullYear() - ageInYears - (currentMonth > birthMonthNum || currentMonth == birthMonthNum && currentDay > birthDate? 0 : 1);

// 20 May 1981
var fictionalBirthDate = new Date(birthYear, birthMonthNum, parseInt(birthDay));
```

Note that *parseInt* is required to trim the ordinal part of the date, so `'20th'` -> `20`. A regular expression could also be used, but parseInt is a bit more self-documenting.

#### Edit

It seems that the "now" date may be any date you choose, so here's a function that accepts an optional *ageDate* parameter that is a date on which the age is true. If no date is provided, it uses the current date.

```
// Calculate a birthdate given the age, birth month, birth date and ageDate on which
// the age is true. If no ageDate is provided, the current date is used.
function calcBirthYear(agetToTurn, birthMonth, birthDay, ageDate) {
    date = ageDate || new Date();
    var currentMonth = date.getMonth();
    var currentDate  = date.getDate();
    var months = {january:0, february:1, march:2, april:3, may:4, june:5, july:6,
                  august:7, september:8, october:9, november:10, december:11};
    var birthMonthNum = months[birthMonth.toLowerCase()];
    var birthDate = parseInt(birthDay);
    var birthYear = date.getFullYear() - agetToTurn - (currentMonth > birthMonthNum || currentMonth == birthMonthNum && currentDay >= birthDate? 0 : 1);

    return new Date(birthYear, birthMonthNum, parseInt(birthDay));
}

console.log(calcBirthYear(10, 'May', '20th', new Date(2032, 1, 1)));    // 20 May 2021
console.log(calcBirthYear(56, 'December', '4th'));                      //  4 Dec 1957
console.log(calcBirthYear(56, 'December', '4th', new Date(3014,2,17))); //  4 Dec 2957
console.log(calcBirthYear(57, 'June', '14th'));                         // 14 Jun 1956
```

The function returns a date object. If only the year is required, then the last line should be:

```
return birthYear;
```

Comment: Thanks RobG, I couldn't get this work, it kept breaking when looking at years in the future. Appreciate your suggesiton.

Comment: If you want the initial date to be something other than the current date, that is easily accommodated, but it was not clear from the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Use the javascript `Date` arithmetic :

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(20);
date.setMonth(4); // May = 4(0 based month index)
date.setYear(date.Year-(date > new Date())?32+1:32);
```

Now `date`  has the exact date of birth of your character.

```
date.getYear();
```

Will give you the year you need.

Comment: I couldn't get his to work ... thanks for commenting though, appreicate it.

Comment: What problem did you face? -- edited with a little more detail.

Comment: I was just getting back the full system date - but I think that was my mistake, I'm really new to javascript and think I might have been passing the wrong variable back to the player. Anyway, I've now gotten this working by using another suggested answer, thank you for your help. I really appreciate it.